# Pagination doesn't work properly on list Scroll view

Tags: android, listview, pagination, scrollview, android-adapter

Following code is used for getting the new data from json on scroll of list view . But after getting the new json it does not add the new one from json instead it takes the same data that are in the first json .

Please Help me with this issue .

My Activity .

```
      public class ProductView extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView list_product;

String json;

ProgressActivity loadingview;

int current_page = 1;

int totalPage = 1;

int Pagecount = 1;

Toolbar toolbar;

GetProductAdapter productAdapter;
List<BeanGetProducts> beanGetProductses = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_view);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.back_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    ImageView img_home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dr_image_home);

    img_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductView.this, AdminAccess.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    list_product = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_products);
    productAdapter = new GetProductAdapter(beanGetProductses, ProductView.this, getApplicationContext());

    list_product.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
        }

        @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItem) {

        int total = firstItem + visibleItemCount;

        if (Pagecount < totalPage) {

            if (total == totalItem) {

                Pagecount++;
                new getProducts(Pagecount).execute();


                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list_product.setAdapter(productAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
});


    new getProducts(current_page).execute();
}


public class getProducts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    int pageNo;


    public getProducts(int pageNo) {
        this.pageNo = pageNo;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {


            loadingview = new ProgressActivity(ProductView.this, "");
            loadingview.setCancelable(false);
            loadingview.show();


        } catch (Exception e) {


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("", String.valueOf(pageNo)));

        json = new ServiceHandler().makeServiceCall(GlobalLinks.mainLink + GlobalLinks.productDetails, ServiceHandler.POST, pairs);


        Log.e("Parameters", "" + pairs);


        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        loadingview.dismiss();

        System.out.println(s);

        try {

            if (!Internet.isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext())) {
                Internet.noInternet(getApplicationContext());
            } else {

                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(null) || s.equalsIgnoreCase("") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("null") || s.length() == 0) {
                    GlobalUse.nullJSON(getApplicationContext());
                } else {

                    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(s);

                    boolean status = mainObject.getBoolean("status");
                    String message = mainObject.getString("message");
                    totalPage = mainObject.getInt("total_page");
                    Log.e("total_page", "" + totalPage);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (status == true) {

                        JSONArray dataArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {


                            JSONObject object = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject getProductObject = object.getJSONObject("GetProduct");

                            BeanGetProducts getProducts = new BeanGetProducts();

                            getProducts.setProduct_id(getProductObject.getString("product_id"));
                            getProducts.setImage(getProductObject.getString("image"));
                            getProducts.setSku(getProductObject.getString("sku"));
                            getProducts.setQuantity(getProductObject.getString("quantity"));
                            getProducts.setPrice(getProductObject.getString("price"));
                            getProducts.setStock_status_id(getProductObject.getString("stock_status_id"));


                            JSONObject product_description = object.getJSONObject("Product_Description");

                            getProducts.setName(product_description.getString("name"));
                            getProducts.setDescription(product_description.getString("description"));

                            JSONObject SpecialPrice = object.getJSONObject("SpecialPrice");

                            getProducts.setSpecialPrice(SpecialPrice.getString("price"));


                            beanGetProductses.add(getProducts);
                        }


                     //   productAdapter = new GetProductAdapter(beanGetProductses, ProductView.this, getApplicationContext());
                        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        list_product.setAdapter(productAdapter);


                    }


                }


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminAccess.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();


}
  }
```

Comment: everytime you make a network call for getting products, you create a new adapter. You should set adapter once in onCreate() method and insert object in list and notify.

Comment: tried it but it reflects the same issue. @SachinSaxena

Comment: Can you post complete code of that activity? Also you can use this endless scroll listener https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: Post the complete code of my activity . And yes i used same link for my reference . @SachinSaxena

Comment: Please tell me what is the pagecount value which you are passing for getting new products from the network.?

Answer (score 0):

Crate a new class named as EndlessScrollListener

```
import android.widget.AbsListView; 

public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum number of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
        {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
        }
        // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + visibleThreshold) >= totalItemCount ) {
            loading = onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    // Returns true if more data is being loaded; returns false if there is no more data to load.
    public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
}
```

Then change your code as below.

The pagecount which you are passing in you asynctask is actually the size of a list. So you can update this variable this after laoding data from the network.

```
public class ProductView extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list_product;

String json;

ProgressActivity loadingview;

int Pagecount = 0

Toolbar toolbar;

GetProductAdapter productAdapter;
List<BeanGetProducts> beanGetProductses = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_view);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.back_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    ImageView img_home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dr_image_home);

    img_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductView.this, AdminAccess.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    list_product = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_products);
    productAdapter = new GetProductAdapter(beanGetProductses, ProductView.this, getApplicationContext());

    // Load first time data and insert into list.
    new getProducts(Pagecount).execute(); 

    list_product.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
          // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
          // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
          new getProducts(Pagecount).execute(); 
          // or loadNextDataFromApi(totalItemsCount); 
          return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.
      }
    });

}


public class getProducts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    int pageNo;
    public getProducts(int pageNo) {
        this.pageNo = pageNo;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {


            loadingv

iew = new ProgressActivity(ProductView.this, "");
                loadingview.setCancelable(false);
                loadingview.show();


            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {


            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("", String.valueOf(pageNo)));

            json = new ServiceHandler().makeServiceCall(GlobalLinks.mainLink + GlobalLinks.productDetails, ServiceHandler.POST, pairs);


            Log.e("Parameters", "" + pairs);


            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loadingview.dismiss();

            System.out.println(s);

            try {

                if (!Internet.isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext())) {
                    Internet.noInternet(getApplicationContext());
                } else {

                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(null) || s.equalsIgnoreCase("") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("null") || s.length() == 0) {
                        GlobalUse.nullJSON(getApplicationContext());
                    } else {

                        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(s);

                        boolean status = mainObject.getBoolean("status");
                        String message = mainObject.getString("message");
                        totalPage = mainObject.getInt("total_page");
                        Log.e("total_page", "" + totalPage);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (status == true) {

                            JSONArray dataArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("data");
    // Update Pagecount here 
Pagecount = Pagecount + dataArray.length();
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {


                                JSONObject object = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject getProductObject = object.getJSONObject("GetProduct");

                                BeanGetProducts getProducts = new BeanGetProducts();

                                getProducts.setProduct_id(getProductObject.getString("product_id"));
                                getProducts.setImage(getProductObject.getString("image"));
                                getProducts.setSku(getProductObject.getString("sku"));
                                getProducts.setQuantity(getProductObject.getString("quantity"));
                                getProducts.setPrice(getProductObject.getString("price"));
                                getProducts.setStock_status_id(getProductObject.getString("stock_status_id"));


                                JSONObject product_description = object.getJSONObject("Product_Description");

                                getProducts.setName(product_description.getString("name"));
                                getProducts.setDescription(product_description.getString("description"));

                                JSONObject SpecialPrice = object.getJSONObject("SpecialPrice");

                                getProducts.setSpecialPrice(SpecialPrice.getString("price"));


                                beanGetProductses.add(getProducts);
                                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminAccess.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


    }

    }
```